# d3.js bar chart new data adding onto bars,

Tags: javascript, d3.js, append, bar-chart

Please see the code below. Data is randomly generated from googlesheets, when get random data button is selected, data is retrieved from the google sheets. When new table button is selected, the bar chart appears.

However if the 1st bar chart that appears 1st value is 5, and when the data updates and the value should be 1, the bar chart look like 6.

I don't want to remove the rect, as I do want to do some transition to show the bars increasing and decreasing. I am currently using: http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js

```
<body>
<div id="change">
  <input type="button" 
    style = "margin-right: 450px;"
    value="New Table" 
    onclick="test()" />
</div>         

<div id="option">
  <input type="button" 
    style = "margin-right: 450px;"
    value="Different Random Data" 
    onclick="remove()"  />
</div>


<div id="table"></div>
<div id="myclonediv"></div>

<script>
  updateCode()
  var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    //width and height
    .attr("width", 300)
    .attr("height", 1000);

  function test() {
    var source = document.getElementById('table');
    var destination = document.getElementById('myclonediv');
    var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
    copy.setAttribute('id', 'myclonediv');
    destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);

    //d3.selectAll("rect").remove();
    //d3.selectAll("text").remove();

    createGraph()
  }

  function createGraph() {
    d3.csv(googlesheets, function(data) {

      //create container - canvas

      //svg = d3.select("svg")

      //add bars  - rectangle 
      canvas.selectAll('svg')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('rect')
        //width - d will reference data, d.age - from csv file * 10 so bars are bigger
        .attr("width", function(d) { return d.Random * 10})
        //was 50 now 48 to allow space between bars
        .attr("height", 48)
        // y function of the index, for each element
        .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i *50})
        //colour blue
        .attr("fill", "blue");

        //.transition()
        //.delay(function(d,i){return i *300;})
        //.duration(100000)
        //.attr("opacity", 1)

        //var newData = parsedCSV.replace(',', '');
        //var test = parsedCSV.substring(parsedCSV.indexOf(",") + 1);

      //text = d3.select("text")
      //add text to each bar - repeat before
      canvas.selectAll("svg")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
        //white text
          .attr("fill", "red")
          //same position on each bar -- + 24 is half of 48 in height -- now middle of bar
          .attr("y", function(d,i) { return i *50+24})
          //what text - d.name
          .text(function(d) { return d.Random; }) 

    }); 


  }

  function remove() {
    var tableCode = d3.select("#table");
    tableCode.selectAll("*").remove();
    updateCode()
  }


  function updateCode() {
    var tabulate = function (data,columns) {                      
       var table = d3.select('#table').append('table')
       var thead = table.append('thead')
       var tbody = table.append('tbody')

       thead.append('tr')
         .selectAll('th')
         .data(columns)
         .enter()
         .append('th')
           .text(function (d) { return d })

       var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
         .data(data)
         .enter()
         .append('tr');

       var cells = rows.selectAll('td')
         .data(function(row) {
            return columns.map(function (column) {
                return { column: column, value: row[column] }
            })
         })
         .enter()
         .append('td')
         .text(function (d) { return d.value })

      return table;
   };

   d3.csv(googlesheets,function (data) {
     var columns = ['Test','Random']
     tabulate(data,columns);                
   });
 }  
</script>

</body>
```

This code works perfectly if I uncomment

```
d3.selectAll("rect").remove();
d3.selectAll("text").remove();
```

But as I want to show the bars increasing and decreasing when data is updated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've tried to simplify the problem a bit and add comments where appropriate:

```
<body>

  <!-- only one button now. just to update the graph -->
  <div id="change">
    <input type="button" 
      style = "margin-right: 450px;"
      value="Update Graph" 
      onclick="updateGraph()" />
  </div>

  <script>
    // Create an svg element and append it to the page body
    // This svg element is now available via the canvas variable
    var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      //width and height
      .attr("width", 300)
      .attr("height", 1000)

    // Initialise the graph immediately when the screen loads
    createGraph();

    // I wasn't sure what data you were getting from the googledocs,
    // so instead of reading data from a csv file, the data is here
    // being generated on demand using this function.

    // generates a dataset of 5 objects
    function createRandomData() {
      var data = [];

      for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        data.push({
          // Generate random number from 3 to 10
          Random: Math.floor(Math.random() * 8) + 3
        });
      }
      return data;
    }

    function createGraph() {

      // generate graph data
      var data = createRandomData();

      // add bars  - rectangle 
      // In your original post, you were trying to select the svg
      // element, but what you need to do is select the rect elements
      // **even though they don't yet exist**.

      // Select all of the rect elements
      canvas.selectAll('rect')
        // There are 5 objects in the dataset, so there should be 5 rect elements
        .data(data)
        // Enter returns a selection for every data object 
        // that doesn't have a matching rect element on the page 
        // (in this case all 5 of them)
        .enter()
        // For each match returned by enter() append a rect
        .append('rect')
          // width - d will reference data, d.age - from csv file * 10 so bars are bigger
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.Random * 10})
          // was 50 now 48 to allow space between bars
          .attr("height", 48)
          // y function of the index, for each element
          .attr("y", function(d, i) { return i * 50})
          // colour of blue is now also in proportion to value
          .attr("fill", function(d) { return "rgb(0,0," + d.Random * 20 + ")"; } );

      // Select all the text elements (none exist yet)
      canvas.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        // For each data item that doesn't yet have a text element
        // append a new one
        .enter()
          .append("text")
          .attr("fill", "white")
          // labels positioned along the x axis at the end of the bar
          .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.Random * 10) - 20; })
          // same position on each bar -- + 24 is half of 48 in height -- now middle of bar
          .attr("y", function(d,i) { return i * 50 + 24})
          .text(function(d) { return d.Random; });
    }

    // Clicking the button will trigger this function
    function updateGraph() {

      // generate new data
      var data = createRandomData();

      // update bars

      // This time when the rects are selected, there are a matching
      // number of existing rect elements and data items. So no need to call
      // enter() to create new elements.
      // Instead, the data values in the existing rects are updated,
      // and a transition is made over the specified duration
      // to the new values.
      canvas.selectAll('rect')
        .data(data)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
          //width - d will reference data, d.age - from csv file * 10 so bars are bigger
          .attr("width", function(d) { return d.Random * 10})
          //colour blue
          .attr("fill", function(d) { return "rgb(0,0," + d.Random * 20 + ")"; });

      // update labels
      canvas.selectAll("text")
        .data(data)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
          .attr("fill", "white")
          // labels positioned along the x axis at the end of the bar
          .attr("x", function(d) { return (d.Random * 10) - 20; })
          // same position on each bar -- + 24 is half of 48 in height -- now middle of bar
          .attr("y", function(d,i) { return i * 50 + 24})
          .text(function(d) { return d.Random; });
    }

  </script>

</body>
```